# Chaining 2 VPNs on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows-7, internet, vpn

I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 7 that can allow me to chain 2 VPNs.

I.e., I have 2 VPN servers, VPN_server01 and VPN_server02. When connecting to Internet I want my Internet connection to go through `My computer <-> VPN_server01 <-> VPN_server02 <-> Internet`.

---

- Operating system: Microsoft Windows 7.
- License: any
- Price: any

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Quora](https://qr.ae/pNvqtT)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.cactusvpn.com/beginners-guide-to-vpn/double-vpn-chain/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200908065714/https://www.cactusvpn.com/beginners-guide-to-vpn/double-vpn-chain/)) gives an interesting list of solutions:

> 1. Doublehop VPNs
> 2. Self-Configurable Multihop VPN Connections
> 3. Router Setup + VPN Client Connections
> 4. Browser Extension + VPN Client Connections
> 5. Host Machine + Virtual Machine

Answer (score -1):

You'd need to have VPN_server01 establish a VPN to VPN_server02 which would then cause this to happen automatically provided the VPN settings were that it route all its traffic through that VPN connection.

The reason for this is that once the traffic leaves your computer to VPN_server01, it's out of your control.